# How does "redux" decouple the different components so they can be tested separately in unit tests?

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm, redux

In the past we saw a big move from traditional MVC to MVVM for user interfaces:

One of the primary motivations for MVVM is that the view and viemmodel are competely indepedently of each other and can work/stay alive without each other. Since the viewmodel doesn't care about the view at all it was also easy to swap components of the view.

In MVC the model is quite often tightly coupled with the view (due to say a handler being called directly from a button press).

Now the new "hotness" seems to be using a redux approach, this is an approach where the whole idea of "model" "view" and "controller" (or another thing that holds the logic) is thrown out of the window. One of the important features from this idea is that data flow is "unidirectional".

I wonder how that influences dependency, wouldn't having only unidirectional bindings mean that the view becomes tightly coupled to the "reducer"? And if one would use a different view, the reducer has to be updated as well?

If that is the case, wouldn't be that a step back?

Comment: It is a step back which is a part of why libraries like MobX which enable solid MVVM are becoming more popular while things like Vue which do MVVM are getting more popular.